# How to insert UNION data into a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to use `UNION` on two tables in order to combine a similar field, then insert that `UNION` data into a different table.

Example:

Table1 has the following fields:

- x
- y
- z

Table2 has the following fields:

- x
- w
- v

I would like to perform `UNION` on x in order to insure there are no duplicate rows, then put that data in another table.

Example:

I would like MainTable to have the following fields:

- x
- y
- z
- w
- v

As you can tell, all of the fields from both Table1 and Table2 exist in MainTable, but x has had `UNION` performed on it.

This SQL code does not work in a query, however, and is giving me `Syntax Error in FROM Clause`:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable(x)

SELECT x
FROM (Table1)

UNION 

SELECT x
FROM (Table2)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you want to insert.

Comment: I haven't used access before so I can't be sure, but are you supposed to put parenthesis around the table names?

Comment: @axblount I took them out and I'm getting the same error, so I'm unsure.

Comment: @HansUp as I said, already tried that, still not getting any different error messages

Comment: You might try `SELECT * INTO MainTable FROM ( [union thing] ) AS some_alias;`

Comment: This works in Access 2010: `INSERT INTO MainTable(x) SELECT sub.x FROM (SELECT x FROM Table1 UNION SELECT x FROM Table2) AS sub`

Comment: I think the easiest way to do something like that is to create two queries. Do the UNION in the first query and make sure the result you see is what you want. Then create another query based on the first query to insert data from your first query into the main table. It should be possible to do all in one query but the two query approach is (at least for non SQL specialist) easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable(x)

FROM

(
SELECT x
FROM (Table1)

UNION 

SELECT x
FROM (Table2)
) as t
```